# Find the number of identical rows between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like below:

```
             check_churn  is_churn
0               True         1
1               True         1
2              False         1
3              False         1
4               True         1
5               True         1
6               True         1
7               True         1
8               True         1
9               True         1
10              True         1
```

I want to identify how many rows is identical. For instance, row 0 is counted since True = 1, also same to row 1. So the answer will be `9` since only 2 of them mismatch.

Comment: should it be 9 ?

Comment: ya is 9, sorry for the typo

Comment: How do you represent the table? Tuple array? Pandas table? Can you give some more practical information?

Comment: its a pandas table

Comment: Whoops, I missed the tag ;-) sorry

Comment: The `is_churn` column is the truth value where the `check_churn` is predicted. I want to see how well it predict the truth value. So I decide to see how many of them actually match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need compare values of columns and count `True`s by `sum`, `True`s are processes like `1`s:

```
print ((df['check_churn'] == df['is_churn']))
0      True
1      True
2     False
3     False
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
dtype: bool


print ((df['check_churn'] == df['is_churn']).sum())
9
```

Another solution is filter and get [`DataFrame.shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html):

```
print (df_train.loc[df_train.check_churn == df_train.is_churn].shape[0])
9
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(2017)
N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'check_churn':np.random.choice([True, False], size=N),
                   'is_churn':np.random.choice([0, 1], size=N)})
print (df)

In [35]: %timeit (df['check_churn'] == df['is_churn']).sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 414 µs per loop

In [36]: %timeit sum(df['check_churn'] & df['is_churn'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 793 µs per loop

In [37]: %timeit (df.loc[df.check_churn == df.is_churn].shape[0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 708 µs per loop
```

---

```
N = 1000000

In [39]: %timeit (df['check_churn'] == df['is_churn']).sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 18.2 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit sum(df['check_churn'] & df['is_churn'])
10 loops, best of 3: 54.7 ms per loop

In [41]: %timeit (df.loc[df.check_churn == df.is_churn].shape[0])
10 loops, best of 3: 23.4 ms per loop

In [42]: %timeit (df['check_churn'] & df['is_churn']).sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 21.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: `print df_train.loc[df_train.check_churn == df_train.is_churn].shape`. This works too. Just figure it out :3

Comment: Do you think `print (df_train.loc[df_train.check_churn == df_train.is_churn].shape[0])` ?

Comment: Yes. It will then return me the amount of row. Thanks. It solved the question. Let's include my solution into yours and will accept this answer after 10 minutes.

Comment: Do some timings! :p

Comment: @MervynLee - is possible `is_churn` values are `0`s ?

Comment: @jezrael nice one! yours was fastest +1. I think however mine has higher readability... or not. you won! :)

Comment: @AntonvBR - plus1 for you too ;) I test `%timeit (df['check_churn'] & df['is_churn']).sum()
10 loops, best of 3: 21.2 ms per loop` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably write it like this:

```
sum(df['check_churn'] & df['is_churn'])
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'check_churn': {0: True,
  1: True,
  2: False,
  3: False,
  4: True,
  5: True,
  6: True,
  7: True,
  8: True,
  9: True,
  10: True},
 'is_churn': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

sum(df['check_churn'] & df['is_churn'])
```